# ErrorProvider like in VB.net for Java

Tags: java, vb.net

Is there any component in java that behaves like the Error Provider in Vb.net? Or what can you suggest for an alternative? I don't want to use a JOptionPane just to show the error.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this help: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0460__GUI-Windows-Forms/GetErrorMessagefromErrorProvider.htm

Comment: is that for .net? I'm looking for a counterpart of errorprovider in java.

Comment: Some open-source java class for ErrorProvider `https://github.com/NiceSystems/hrider/blob/master/src/main/java/hrider/ui/controls/ErrorProvider.java` Did not test this.

Answer (score 0):

```
package main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JWindow;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/**
 *
 * @author Alejandro Ramirez Macias
 */
public class ErrorProvider {
    static JWindow win;
    static Timer tmrHide;
    static Timer tmrOpacity;
    static int time;  

    public static void setError(Component component, String message) {
        if (win == null) {
            tmrHide = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    System.out.println("TimerHide");
                    tmrHide.stop();
                    time = 1000; // 1 second
                    tmrOpacity.start();
                }
            });

            // each 100 ms
            tmrOpacity = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    System.out.println("TimerOpacity");
                    time -= 100;
                    win.setOpacity((float) (time * 0.001)); // 0.9,0.8...,0.1
                    if (time == 100) {
                        tmrOpacity.stop();
                        win.dispose();
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            tmrHide.stop();
            tmrOpacity.stop();
            win.dispose();            
        }

        win = new JWindow();

        // make the background transparent 
        win.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));

        // create panel
        JPanel p = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                int w = g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(message);
                int h = g.getFontMetrics().getHeight();
                                
                // fill rect
                g.setColor(Color.PINK);
                g.fillRect(4, 4, w + 30, h + 10);

                // line rect
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.drawRect(4, 4, w + 30, h + 10);

                // set the color of text
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawString(message, 20, 22);

                // draw the shadow of the toast 
                int t = 250; // tranparent
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    t -= 60;
                    g.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0, t));
                    g.drawRect(
                            3 - i, // x
                            3 - i, // y
                            w + 30 + i * 2, // w 
                            h + 10 + i * 2  // h
                    );
                }               
            }
        };        
        int w = p.getFontMetrics(p.getFont()).stringWidth(message);
        int h = p.getFontMetrics(p.getFont()).getHeight();
        win.add(p);
        win.setSize(w + 30 + 6, h + 10 + 6); // 3: lines of shadow by side
        win.setLocation(component.getLocation());        
        //win.setOpacity(1);
        win.setVisible(true);
        tmrHide.start();
    }
}
```

Call the static function: **ErrorProvider.setError(jTextBox1, "Error text is empty");**

Code open source: https://github.com/alexudg/netbeans-ballontip